# How to load a website URL in UIWebView without getting frozen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have this below piece of code where I am opening a UIwebview with a website URL which is a pretty heavy ecommerce site. Once I start navigating through the site, I hit a block where the page starts loading but does not complete it.
Like in my UIWebViewDelegate, webViewDidStartLoad is called but webViewDidFinishLoad is not getting called...

my viewcontroller.h file:

```
            #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

            @interface WVTesterViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

            @end
```

my .m file:

```
            #import "WVTesterViewController.h"

            @interface WVTesterViewController ()

            @end

            @implementation WVTesterViewController

            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

                UIWebView *view = self.view.subviews[0];
                view.delegate = self;
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<<< MY WEBSITE URL >>>"];
                [view loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
            }

            - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to load with error :%@",[error debugDescription]);
            }

            - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
            {
                NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad :");
            }

            - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
            {
                NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad :");
            }

            - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
            {
                NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest :");
                return true;
            }

            - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
            {
                [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }

            @end
```

Any idea why is this happening and below is the screen cap of my web thread which is hanging and my app is dead in the water.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufmbncjbz0x0vbi/Screenshot%202015-03-06%2015.41.08.png?dl=0

**Additional info**

- The CPU usage of the `WebThread` is 100%, suggesting that an infinite loop is happening.
- The names of the methods being called by the web thread suggest the loop is happening during the initial page load.
- The deadlock happens when the Main thread needs to run code on the `WebThread`, causing it to block indefinitely waiting for the infinite loop to end
- In production code the `UIWebView` is an `IBOutlet` property of the `UIViewController`, but in our minimal reproducible example we tried to avoid IB magic as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to add the webview object as a property to your WVTesterViewController class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *yourWebView;
```

and in you implementation file (.m file) set the delegate of your web view property as follows:

```
[self.yourWebView setDelegate:self];
[self.yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourWebsiteURL.com"]]];
```

Try NSURLProtocol you will have better control over loading and loading progress.